# Where can I download US secondary (high school, etc) educational test score data for school districts, individual schools, etc?

Tags: usa, education

This has so far been a surprising difficult task. It appears some aspect of public policy sees it fit to make this data difficult to obtain(?) I'm sure its out there though. No child left behind data, SAT/ACT score statistics for school districts, something like that. I'm looking for (United States) middle & high school academic performance data, not academic "attainment", which is very easy information to obtain. Obviously, I'd love to get it at a census block group level of geographic resolution, but anything at this point beneath the county or state level would be great.

Comment: one personal update: I had much more success finding school-specific data at the state level. Even south carolina now releases all sorts of standardized test score statistics (averages & percentage tested) for individual schools in xls. Was able to convert a bunch of old pdf's into spreadsheets fairly easy using the relatively new open source tool called "Tabula"

Comment: The final trick, however, is then finding the public high school, middle school and elementary school district areas that correspond to those test scores. Those must be obtained at the county-level, and are thus only available online in certain areas. Otherwise, they might try to confine you to a question-based knowledge system where you have to ask one million questions to get the map of knowledge that you want. The real question you should ask yourself at this point is, what tools are THEY using to get that information for each of your questions? Storm the bastille with FOIAs, I always say

Comment: of course, in South Carolina and New York (for example, according to a book written by the zillow ceo and chief economist), home & rent values do not correspond with public school test scores. Private school data is normally private, so that's always a dark pool data skewer to take into account

Answer (score 4):

NCES' School District Demographics System map viewer offers data for individual school districts, of particular importance to this question: spatial data, and census/acs data:
http://nces.ed.gov/surveys/sdds/ed/index.asp

(Some) State-wide District Data:
California Department of Education Postsecondary Preparation SAT, ACT, and AP Test Results (County, District and School Reports)
http://www.cde.ca.gov/ds/sp/ai/
Massachussetts Department of Elementary and Secondary Education SAT Performance Results (2004-05 -- 2013-14) by School District
http://profiles.doe.mass.edu/state_report/sat_perf.aspx
NYC Open Data search for Education (SAT results, School Districts GIS, Math Test Results, etc.)
https://nycopendata.socrata.com/data?cat=education
Pennslyvania ACT Test Scores 2013
https://www.opendataphilly.org/dataset/act-test-scores
Pennsylvania SAT Scores 2001-2010
https://www.opendataphilly.org/dataset/sat-scores-2001-2010
District Profiles NAEP (Middle School and Younger)
http://nces.ed.gov/nationsreportcard/districts/

South Carolina standardized test score statistics for individual schools and districts:
 https://ed.sc.gov/data/national-assessments/

More resources:
ED Data Inventory
http://datainventory.ed.gov/
U.S. Department of Education Public Data Listing
http://www2.ed.gov/about/data/list.html
National Center for Education Statistics Data Tools
http://nces.ed.gov/datatools/index.asp?DataToolSectionID=5
Nations Report Card
http://www.nationsreportcard.gov/